# ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS No KDE-Start-Button and Desktop after update

Tags: kubuntu, kde5

I have the following configuration
Betriebssystem: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE-Plasma-Version: 5.24.6
KDE-Frameworks-Version: 5.92.0
Qt-Version: 5.15.3
Kernel-Version: 5.15.0-53-generic (64-bit)
Grafik-Plattform: X11
Prozessoren: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz
Speicher: 11,7 GiB Arbeitsspeicher
Grafikprozessor: AMD RV730

After the last dist-upgrade there is no KDE-Start-Button and no Desktop-background. I can only start my applications by the commandline...

I thried the following:
killall plasmashell
kstart plasmashell
plasmashell: Kein Prozess gefunden
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended
root@# QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Aborting shell load: The activity manager daemon (kactivitymanagerd) is not running.
If this Plasma has been installed into a custom prefix, verify that its D-Bus services dir is known to the system for the daemon to be activatable.
starting invalid corona "org.kde.plasma.desktop"

But NO change!

What should I do instead?

Comment: Check in your logs (`/var/log/apt/term.log`) if some packages got removed. I guess that `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` will solve your problem. I use Ubuntustudio and it removed the packages `plasma-desktop` and `ubuntustudio-desktop` and I had to install `ubuntustudio-desktop` which installed `plasma-desktop` as a dependency. You will have to logout and back in after installing the missing packages.

Comment: If you use `apt full-upgrade` or it's equivalent `apt dist-upgrade` make sure to read the terminal output carefully before you proceed. It tells you exactly what's going to happen and if you see it will remove packages you should probably not proceed before knowing what's going on .

Answer (score 1):

On my Dell XPS 13 9310 :

After updating my Kubuntu 22.04 this morning, then after reboot. I had this problem:

Right after login: I first have a black screen for several seconds (the one that displays the KDE logo). And then I have a totally black screen (on this one, I just see my mouse cursor that I can move).

I also tried (in terminal) to create a new user. And even when logging in with this new user, I have a black screen after logging in.

So I reinstalled Kubuntu 22.04 from scratch...

Once the installation was finished, I still had a display bug just after logging in… I could see the bottom taskbar, but not the desktop…

And it was then by doing a "sudo apt update" then "sudo apt upgrade" then "reboot", that it fixed this bug for me...

Then I still had fun reinstalling my OS from scratch. And this time, right after installation, this bug was gone.

So it was definitely a Kubuntu 22.04 update bug (and not a bug on my part). A bug that took a few hours to fix (KDE update bug? or Display Driver update bug? I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (Kubuntu 22.04 as well), apt dist-upgrade wants to uninstall two packages (in German):

```
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
kubuntu-desktop (1.418)
plasma-desktop (4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.1)
```

Try to re-install those packages:

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop
```